# Slowness with Node.js FS : how can I list files faster?

Tags: node.js, performance, fs

I just want to read files names from a dir :

```
const fs = require('fs');    
fs.readdir("repo/_posts", (err, files) => {     
  files.forEach(file => {
    res.write(file + "\n");      
  });   
})
```

With only a 15 files, it is very slow, it takes several seconds to display the file names. What did I do wrong?

Edit : as suggested by @Darin Dimitrov in the comments, I've tried to replace res.write by console.log, then it's fast. Is res.write a bad practice in a loop or something similar?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that the `fs.readdir` is slow and not some other part of the HTTP pipeline? Can you try putting this in a separate `test.js` file that does only this call and prints the file names to the console and see if it behaves the same?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you're right. It's faster if I do this. It's fast too if I only print to the console, but it's slow when I use res.write.

Comment: Did you try hitting that URL with cURL to see if the `res.write()` output is shown immediately? Most likely the browser is buffering the output (for various reasons, including content encoding sniffing), so you do not see it immediately.

Comment: @mscdex I think you're right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will buffer output received from the server for a variety of reasons (including content encoding detection) and some of them may buffer more than others. If you can access the same url via a utility such as cURL and you see the expected output in a much more timely manner, then this confirms the browser buffering "issue."